# Is there a 1 hit point minimum each level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement, hit-points

It came up in a game after we leveled that you always gain at least 1 hp when you level up, even if you have a negative con which would cause you to lose hp for that level. But I can't find it anywhere.

Its' not in [combat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Hit-Points), [level advancement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/), [building characters](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/character-creation/), [conditions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/), or [common terms](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/).

Am I wrong about this or just not looking in the right place?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's in the [definitions of ability scores](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/#Constitution_Con) (Core Rulebook p.16).

> You apply your character’s Constitution modifier to:
>
> Each roll of a Hit Die (though a penalty can never drop a result below 1—that is, a character always gains at least 1 hit point each time he advances in level).